# Hiding window from taskbar in C# with WinAPI

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, window, taskbar

Believe me, I have Googled it and expected it to be a fairly easy find - turns out it isn't.
I have my window handle, but no form. How do I do it? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Declare these:

```
 [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, int dwNewLong);
private const int GWL_EX_STYLE = -20;
private const int WS_EX_APPWINDOW = 0x00040000, WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW = 0x00000080;
```

And then use this before the form is shown:

```
SetWindowLong(handle, GWL_EX_STYLE, (GetWindowLong(handle, GWL_EX_STYLE) | WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW) & ~WS_EX_APPWINDOW);
```

(change handle to whatever your window handle is stored in)

Answer (score 3):

Set Form's ShowInTaskbar property to false.

Comment: With WinAPI, not .NET properties.