# Hide a WPF form from Alt+Tab

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am wanting to hide a WPF window that has `WindowStyle="None"` , `AllowTransparency="True"` and `ShowInTaskbar="False"` from the task menu (Alt+Tab).

I have already researched this but all the results appear to be for WinForms or don't have an answer. Here are some of the sources I have already looked into:

1. [Same question on VS community WITHOUT an answer](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/351728/provide-a-way-for-wpf-applications-to-easily-hide.html)
2. [Same question on StackOverflow but for WinForms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27378767/hiding-borderless-window-from-alttab-menu)
3. [Same question but for WinForms on generic site](http://www.csharp411.com/hide-form-from-alttab/)
4. [This doesn't meet my requirements because I still want the WPF window to be visible, just not seen in the Alt+Tab menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23672595/how-to-hide-winform-or-wpf-application-from-alttab-and-from-task-managers-ap/23672596)

Here is my XAML code:

```
<Window x:Class="DesktopInfo.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DesktopInfo"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" WindowStyle="None" AllowsTransparency="True"  Background="Transparent" ShowInTaskbar="False" Loaded="FormLoaded">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Text="Testing" Name="UsernameTextBlock" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="White"/>
        <TextBlock Name="ComputernameTextBlock" Grid.Row="1" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="White"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Here is my C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DesktopInfo
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    /// 
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

No matter what I try, I cannot get the WPF form to not show up in the Alt+Tab menu. Any help is very much appreciated :)

**UPDATE AFTER DUPLICATE FLAG**
After looking at the link that was provided (and previously viewed before asking this question), I would like to state that I, in fact, found the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3260757/hiding-window-from-taskbar-in-c-sharp-with-winapi) and will post my full code as an answer to this question :)

Comment: [What about this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23672595/how-to-hide-winform-or-wpf-application-from-alttab-and-from-task-managers-ap/23672596)

Comment: @John Thank you for the link, I will update my question with why this doesn't fit my requirements :)

Comment: Did you try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/357076/best-way-to-hide-a-window-from-the-alt-tab-program-switcher

Comment: @Andy I actually saw this and it looked promising. Some of the comments on the answer state that it no longer works, however. It looks like a lot of work and to be honest I'm not sure where the code should go.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to hide a window from the Alt-Tab program switcher?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/357076/best-way-to-hide-a-window-from-the-alt-tab-program-switcher)

Comment: Wait, the title says WPF but you're using Windows.Forms?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

My final code following the answer from this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3260757/hiding-window-from-taskbar-in-c-sharp-with-winapi) can be seen below:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Interop;

namespace DesktopInfo
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    /// 
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, int dwNewLong);
        private const int GWL_EX_STYLE = -20;
        private const int WS_EX_APPWINDOW = 0x00040000, WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW = 0x00000080;

        public MainWindow() => InitializeComponent();
        
        //Form loaded event handler
        void FormLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
        {
            //Variable to hold the handle for the form
            var helper = new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle;
            //Performing some magic to hide the form from Alt+Tab
            SetWindowLong(helper, GWL_EX_STYLE, (GetWindowLong(helper, GWL_EX_STYLE) | WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW) & ~WS_EX_APPWINDOW);
            
        }
    }
}
```

My form now runs as a background task, is still visible and cannot be seen in the Alt+Tab menu. Thank you, everyone, for your help :) I'm a little ashamed I didn't find the winning link before posting the question.

Comment: You're a saint!!